# Why multithreaded version of array elements sum is faster even with lock?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am comparing two versions of the computation of array elements sum: serialized and parallelized one. For the parallelized version, I acquire a lock in the beginning of function that computes a partial sum. Since it will make partial sums to be computed sequentially, I expect that parallelized version will be slower than the serial one. However, when the ratio of the array size to the thread pool size is high, the parallelized version is faster. Could you explain why?

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <thread>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <chrono>
#include <mutex>
#include <random>
#include <atomic>

int total_entries;
float sum;
size_t occupancy;
std::mutex m;

#define SIZE 500000
#define THREAD_POOL 50

void fill_detector(std::vector<float> &det, size_t n = SIZE) {
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_real_distribution<float> distribution(-0.2, 1.0);

    if (!det.empty())
        det.erase(det.begin(), det.end());
    det.reserve(n);

    for (size_t i = 0; i<n; ++i)
        det.push_back(distribution(generator));
}

size_t serial_occupancy(std::vector<float> &det) {
    size_t sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < det.size(); ++i) {
        if (det[i] > 0.0f) {
            ++sum;
        }
    }
    return sum;
}

void partial_occupancy(std::vector<float> &det, size_t begin, size_t end) {
    m.lock();
    for (size_t i = begin; i<end; ++i) {
        if (det[i] > 0.0f) {
            ++occupancy;
        }
        //std::cout << i << " ";
    }
    m.unlock();
}

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    std::vector<float> det;

    fill_detector(det, SIZE);

    // Serial calculation

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::cout << "Occupancy is " << serial_occupancy(det) << std::endl;

    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto duration = end - start;
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>(duration).count() << std::endl;

    // Multithreaded calculation
    start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    occupancy = 0;
    std::thread pool[THREAD_POOL];
    size_t chunk = SIZE / THREAD_POOL;


    for (size_t t = 0; t<THREAD_POOL; ++t) {
        pool[t] = std::thread(partial_occupancy, std::ref(det), chunk*t, chunk*(t + 1));
    }


    for (int t = 0; t<THREAD_POOL; ++t)
        pool[t].join();

    std::cout << "Multi-thread occupancy is " << occupancy << std::endl;
    end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration = end - start;
    std::cout << std::chrono::duration<float, std::milli>(duration).count() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I can't reproduce that in my machine.

Comment: @amchacon You mean that the serial version is always faster on your machine or that the code does not compile?

Comment: You use different code for the two cases.

Comment: @gnasher729 Could you point important differences? Because I don't khow how to make `serial_occupancy` and `partial_occupancy` more similar

Comment: So you are benchmarking in debug mode? In release mode the non-locked code is 3 times faster than the one with locks.

Comment: @BoPersson Indeed, the problem was there. Thank you!